# Set Windows/AD password so that it "never expires"?

Tags: c#, directoryentry

Here is my code:

```
using (DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName +    ",computer"))
{
   DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add(username, "user");
   string password = username + "123";
   NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
   NewUser.CommitChanges();
   NewUser.Close();
   DirectoryEntry grp;
   grp = AD.Children.Find(groupname, "group");
   if (grp != null)
    {
      grp.Invoke("Add", new object[] { NewUser.Path.ToString() });
    }
}
```

And what i want to do is to create a windows user and set the password never expired ,
But i do not know how to do this ?

Comment: Check out this question on how to query for that, it should give you some clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246945/active-directory-check-if-password-never-expires

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*EDITED

For domain accounts:

```
int NON_EXPIRE_FLAG = 0x10000;
val = (int) NewUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
NewUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val | NON_EXPIRE_FLAG;
NewUser.CommitChanges();
```

For local accounts:

I believe you'd use "UserFlags" instead of userAccountControl.
Also you would have to use ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD flag instead of NON_EXPIRE_FLAG as described in [an article by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/winnt-password-never-expires)

Comment: I have tried ,but it does not work; Buy the way, the os system is windows server 2003 ? Does it matter?

Comment: Sorry, when get the NewUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value , the application throw the System.NullReferenceException....

Comment: I think for a local account the property is "userFlags" instead of "userAccountControl" (which is for domain accounts)

Answer (score 8):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a machine context and easily create new users on your local server:

```
// set up machine-level context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
{
    // create new user
    UserPrincipal newUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

    // set some properties
    newUser.SamAccountName = "Sam";
    newUser.DisplayName = "Sam Doe";

    // define new user to be enabled and password never expires
    newUser.Enabled = true;
    newUser.PasswordNeverExpires = true;

    // save new user
    newUser.Save();
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to resolve this issue:
[image]

```
// Add new user to OU
var username = "testuser_01";
var userDn = "LDAP://yourdomain.local:389/OU=testou,cn=yourdomain,cn=local";
var ouUserEntry = new DirectoryEntry(userDn, "yourAdminUser", "yourAdminPassword", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
var newUserEntry = ouUserEntry.Children.Add("CN="+ username, "user");
newUserEntry.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = username;
newUserEntry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = username + "@abc.com";
newUserEntry.Properties["displayName"].Value = username;

// Commit before enable account
newUserEntry.CommitChanges();

// Set password
newUserEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", "yourUserPassword");

// Enable Account & Password never expired (NORMAL_ACCOUNT | DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD)
newUserEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 66080; // integer value in image above
newUserEntry.CommitChanges();
```