# how to set "password never expires" through C# code

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

With below code, I am able to create a user with password, but how to enable "password never expires" flag?

[image]

```
using (var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

    process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"user test-user Password1 /add";
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Chek https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025495/set-windows-ad-password-so-that-it-never-expires. You should not be using "net" calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Windows/AD password so that it "never expires"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025495/set-windows-ad-password-so-that-it-never-expires)

Answer (score 0):

The [`net user` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771865(v%3Dws.11)) says there is an `expires` option that ca used with `never`, like this:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"user test-user Password1 /add /expires:never";
```

But you should probably not use `net user` in your C# code, it's bad practice calling shell processes when there are alternatives.

Comment: Can you give an example of an alternatives

Comment: I think you got some good links in the comments to your question

Comment: It's not my question, but thanks

Comment: Thsis is not working

Comment: This is just to set the account expiry and not the password expiry.