# Setting Password Never Expires for new AD user using System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry (ADLDS, ADAM, Active Directory Application Mode)

Tags: c#, active-directory, passwords, directoryentry

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025495/set-windows-ad-password-so-that-it-never-expires) and tried with both "userPrincipalName" and "userFlags" and I'm receiving "The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist" in both cases.

I am able to set the attribute with the following in Powershell

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'cn -like "*username*"' -Server <serveraddrress> -SearchBase "<searchbase>" | Set-ADUser -PasswordNeverExpires:$True
```

My C# code is as follows, it works fine if I remove the line setting userAccountControl, but it creates the user with Password Never Expires = FALSE

```
using (var dirEntry = entry.Children.Add("CN=" + username, "user"))
{
    dirEntry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = string.Format("{0}@principal", username);
    dirEntry.CommitChanges();
    dirEntry.Options.PasswordPort = port;
    dirEntry.Options.PasswordEncoding = PasswordEncodingMethod.PasswordEncodingClear;
    dirEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", password);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
         dirEntry.Properties["mail"].Value = email;
    dirEntry.Properties["msDS-UserAccountDisabled"].Value = "FALSE";

    //this doesn't work with both "userAccountControl" and "userFlags"
    dirEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = (int)(dirEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value ?? 0) | 0x10000;

    dirEntry.CommitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM)? This line makes me think you are:

```
dirEntry.Properties["msDS-UserAccountDisabled"].Value = "FALSE";
```

That attribute doesn't exist in normal Active Directory. So if that's working for you, then you are using ADAM.

If you are using ADAM, then use the [`msDS-UserDontExpirePassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-msds-userdontexpirepassword) attribute to make the password not expire:

```
dirEntry.Properties["msDS-UserDontExpirePassword"].Value = true;
```

If you are not using ADAM, then the `"msDS-UserAccountDisabled` doesn't exist and you shouldn't be using that. Instead, use `userAccountControl` to set both.

Since you just created the account, you don't need to worry about what the value already was, you can just set it to a specific value. Assuming you want it enabled with the "don't expire password" flag, then you can use this:

```
//NORMAL_ACCOUNT | DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD
dirEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x0200 | 0x10000;
```

You can leave each value separated like that, or just use the resulting decimal value of `66048`.

Comment: thanks! Will try it soon. Need to do some reading on AD in general...   dirEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"] was null, thus the check, but it didn't help as it turned out.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably running an ADAM instance. In normal AD, `userAccountControl` is never null.